# Next js is not making a request to the API endpoint and getting 404 on some dynamic route page (Only happens in deployment)

Tags: javascript, http, next.js, production

i have this code:

```js
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import {Dialog} from '@mui/material'
import axios from 'axios'
import HOST from "../../../config";
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import styles from '../../../styles/styling/verify.module.css'

/*
export async function getServerSideProps({params}){
    try{
        let res = await axios.get(`${HOST}verify/${params.token}/${params.user}/`)
        let token = await res.json()
        return {
            props:{token}
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        return {
            props:[]
        }
    }
}

*/



export default function Verify(){
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [domLoaded,setDomLoaded] = useState(false)
    const [error,setError] = useState(null)
    
    const redirect = useRouter()
    const {token} = redirect.query;
    const {user} = redirect.query;

    useEffect(() => {

            

        if(redirect.isReady){
    
        axios.get(`${HOST}verify/${token}/${user}/`).then((res)=>{
            setMessage(res.data)

        
        }).catch((e)=>{
            setError(e.response.data)
      
            
        
        })
    }
}



    ,[redirect.isReady])
    if(error){
        return(
            <div style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',height:'100vh'}}>
                <h1>{error}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

    
    return (

      
        <Dialog open={true} onClose={setTimeout(()=>{
            redirect.replace('/')
        },2000)}
         className={styles['verify-div']}>
           <div style={{color:'green',padding:'25px',fontSize:'18px'}}>{message}</div>
        </Dialog>
    )

}
```

now whether i comment out the GSSR or not, it gives me the same result

whenever i try to directly access the page such as `somehost/verify/token/my_username/` i get 404 not found, however the plot twist here is the network tab, i found out that next js is not sending a request to the backend at all, take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

as you can see the document, and there is literally no request to the endpoint

also, when trying to open the `document` section of network tab (the one that name end with outlook.com)

i get this response from **next.js**:

[image]

the response in text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><meta name="next-head-count" content="2" /><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/54cef39bf73ec613.css" as="style" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/54cef39bf73ec613.css" data-n-g="" /><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-eade17c8dc1278e8.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-2c79e2a64abdb08b.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-2169995c845281bd.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-551288648335980e.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_error-47e526b08b70a03d.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/rUU0jFZyThGuJlejbFceh/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/rUU0jFZyThGuJlejbFceh/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script><style data-styled="" data-styled-version="5.3.6"></style></head><body><div id="__next"></div><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"statusCode":404}},"page":"/_error","query":{},"buildId":"rUU0jFZyThGuJlejbFceh","nextExport":true,"isFallback":false,"gip":true,"scriptLoader":[]}</script></body></html>
```

again, this only happens in production mode, in dev mode everything works as normal

I deploy my frontend in cloudflare if that matters at all.

On a side note, i tried to log the token, and user, and to see if i get any error in dev mode, everything seems to work fine.

EDIT:

this is how the folder and files are structured for the dynamic routing [image]

Comment: can you share project  github ?

Comment: do i need to share the whole project??!

Comment: if possible or specific code related is also fine .

Comment: the code i pasted above represent `[user]`.js which is where the problem happen.